# combine three queries

Tags: c#, linq

How can I combine these 3 queries together and return them as datatable:

## 1:

```
var TDD = 0;
                var queryTDD = (from x in db.GetAll<WMINO>()
                                 join y in db.GetAll<WMCTM>()
                                 on x.PO_ID equals y.Contract_ID
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     TDD = x.Payable,
                                 });
```

## 2:

```
 Decimal TotalToDatePayable = 0;
            TotalToDatePayable = ((from ori in db.GetAll<WMPORI>()
                                      join ctm in db.GetAll<WMCTM>()
                                      on ori.CTMSysID equals ctm.CTMSysID
                                      select ori.ExB4Taxes).Sum());
```

## 3:

```
  var query = from ctm in db.GetAll<WMCTM>()
                        join vnm in db.GetAll<WMVNM>()
                        on ctm.VendSysID equals vnm.VendSysID
                        where ctm.WONOs == workOrder && ctm.TransType == "Purchase Order"


select new
                            {
                                ctm.CTMSysID,
                                ctm.Contract_ID,
                                ctm.VNM_ID};`
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: What would the purpose of combining those queries be? I'm not even sure what you *mean*. I'm also not even sure what the first query is supposed to be doing, with that unused `TDD` variable...

Comment: Also, haven't you *just* asked this question? [Adding query results into desired query  or Subqueries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790283/adding-query-results-into-desired-query-or-subqueries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with this because each query has different result and using different columns and condition....

There is no meaning in combining this queries.............

Comment: Exactly. Well, it's *possible* to "combine" them into a single set of LINQ statements, but as you note, there would be no meaning to it! It would only complicate things, and likely make performance horrible.